# Batch script to find and replace text in sub folder files

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to get the following code to run through all the sub directories of one directory that the script is run from:

```
for /r %%I in ('dir/b *.ucf') do @call :Start "%%I"

:Start
copy x\*.ucf > nul
Set old=_USTN_PROJECT
Set new=#

Set old1=#NAME
Set new1=_USTN_PROJECTNAME

:main

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir/b *.ucf') do (
call :sub1 %%a
move/y NEWFILE %%a
call :sub2 %%a
move/y NEWFILE1 %%a
)

goto :eof

:sub1
@echo off > NEWFILE & setLocal enableDELAYedeXpansioN
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%i in (%1) do (
set S=%%i
set S=!S:%old%=%new%!
echo.!S!
)>> NEWFILE
echo _USTN_PROJECT          = $(_USTN_WORKSPACEROOT)Projects/EPR-Projects/>> NEWFILE
goto :eof

:sub2
@echo off > NEWFILE1 & setLocal enableDELAYedeXpansioN
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%j in (%1) do (
set T=%%j
set T=!T:%old1%=%new1%!
echo.!T!
) >> NEWFILE1
```

Without the 'for /r' statement I can run the batch within a target directory and it works but in the current version although it appears to look in each directory if fails to locate the files - what am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

```
for /r %%I in ('dir/b *.ucf') do @call :Start "%%I"
```

-->> You are attempting to perform a `for /r` which will take the parenthesised argument as
   a filename-to-match. It's unlikely to find that filename. Possibly you want

```
for /r %%I in (*.ucf) do @call :Start "%%I"
```

which will recursively scan for `*.ucf` files and apply the entire pathname to `%%I`

-->> Having finished the `for` loop, batch will simply continue on through this label.
This is probably not what you want to do.

```
:Start
```

-->> Bad name for a label because `START` is a cmd keyword.

```
copy x\*.ucf > nul
```

-->> No idea what this command is expected to do.

```
Set old=_USTN_PROJECT
Set new=#

Set old1=#NAME
Set new1=_USTN_PROJECTNAME
```

-->> Aha. so you've set up `old(1)` and `new(1)`.
-->> At this time, `%1` contains the full filename of the target `.ucf` file (if you adopted the change I suggested)

```
:main

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir/b *.ucf') do (
```

-->> now you're scanning a list of the `.ucf files` **in the current directory** so the filename is presented to `%%a`. You probably should use `%1` in place of `%%a` since this contains the full filename from the original `for /r`

```
call :sub1 %%a
move/y NEWFILE %%a
call :sub2 %%a
move/y NEWFILE1 %%a
```

-->> make two substitutions; first change old to new; replace the file then change old1 to new1 and replace the file again. Very complex, but it will work. **But** your code uses `%%a` which is a filename only from the current directory. You probably want `%1` which is the full filename from the original `for/r`

```
)

goto :eof
```

-->> Now follow two routines which will perform a substitution each; could probably be simplified and combined into one operation - if we knew what the overall scheme was...

```
:sub1
@echo off > NEWFILE & setLocal enableDELAYedeXpansioN
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%i in (%1) do (
set S=%%i
set S=!S:%old%=%new%!
echo.!S!
)>> NEWFILE
echo _USTN_PROJECT          = $(_USTN_WORKSPACEROOT)Projects/EPR-Projects/>> NEWFILE
goto :eof

:sub2
@echo off > NEWFILE1 & setLocal enableDELAYedeXpansioN
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%j in (%1) do (
set T=%%j
set T=!T:%old1%=%new1%!
echo.!T!
) >> NEWFILE1
```

All rather confusing, but perhaps my comments will aid a resolution.

Comment: The original code didn't contain the for /r statement and was used to loop through all the .UCF files in the same directory as the code. The purpose is to find and replace text in these files which are just renamed .txt files. The reason for running two replacements is each file contains more than one line with a similar target string, the first run incorrectly replaces one line in each file so I need the second run to reset it, not elegant but it works. I need to run this in multiple subdirectories and this is where it stops working. I have tried the suggestions but it doesn't make the edits.

Comment: Try using the edit button to amend your question and add-in your current code (don't delete what you've already posted.) We then have a starting point from which we can work.

Comment: Sorry, I hit a return and posted by mistake, I tried editing but took longer than the 5 mins allowed! - Unfortunately your response came through a little too late for me and I had taken the painful decision to manually edit every file. It would be good to understand why the code failed with the for /r.